# Iterate Database Records in PHP while array indexes are different for deifferent products

Tags: php, mysql

I have an item's value table that is related to attribute table.
if an item query is execute, its attributes values are different
i need to print these values i use these

```
$appearanceSql = "SELECT * FROM values WHERE item_id='$itemID'";
$appearanceResults = $conn->query($appearanceSql);
if($appearanceResults->num_row>0){
//how to loop through to iterate the values of the product if the product have different attributes like mobile phones have some different attributes than a laptop
```

}

Comment: can you show the ouput

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: actually, i need to echo all attributes associated with the item id. 
table strucuture is
val_id
item_id
att_name (different attributes based on category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you misspelled `num_row`, it should be `num_rows`.

And here is how you iterate through result:

```
$appearanceSql = "SELECT * FROM values WHERE item_id='$itemID'";
$appearanceResults = $conn->query($appearanceSql);
if($appearanceResults->num_rows > 0){
    foreach ($row = $appearanceResults->fetch_assoc()) {
        // $row is the row from result
        // $row['*column name*'] - to get column data
    }
}
```

Here is a quick [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) how to iterate through result.

Comment: but what i do if $row['*colum name*'] are different for different types of products. 
can i simply add this in another array and echo attributes as array[0], array[1] something like this

Comment: You column name is the same for all. the values in the column are different.